# Making index sizes more efficient in Postgres10 when indexing most fields in a table

Tags: postgresql

I've got a 3 field table with some time series data in it. The fields are a timestamp, what I'll call a device number and the measured value. The table has about 550 million records in it and is 27GB.

The table has a compound index incorporating the timestamp and the device number. The table will always be queried via these two values, virtually without exception. The index is 16GB.

Here are the definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE rollup_by_minute (
    minute timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    dev_id integer NOT NULL,
    value bigint DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_rollup_by_minute_minute_dev_id ON
    rollup_by_minute USING btree (minute, dev_id);
```

This seems to be an unhappy condition. I'm basically replicating 2/3 of the table in the index with no real way around it. In something like MS-SQL I would think I could use a clustered index for this.

Is there anything I can do in Postgres to make this a little more space efficient?

P.S. At this point I am almost tempted to just put the last field in the index so that I can get everything from there and skip accessing the heap altogether. I'd just have to suck up the fact that every table record is double sized.

Comment: I think PostgreSQL has no Index organized tables, the CLUSTER activity only reorders heap tables according to a given index (which helps for scanning this data). If you need the timeseries in PSQL using a Index covering all 3 columns seems like the only option if you need fast query.

Comment: With Postgres 10 (or older) there is no way to optimize this. With Postgres 11 (to be relased in Q4/2018) you can add the `value` column to the unique index using the `include (...)` option: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/sql-createindex.html  which is still no ideal, but better than a second index

Comment: I did more digging and a BRIN index is close to what I need. I tried it against a copy of the table and the index clocked in at 1.1 MB. 

Query time shifted from being sub 1ms or 100ms (for b-tree depending on whether it was hot) to a reliable ~12ms regardless, which makes sense based on how they work (like a rainbow table). I kind of like that predictable behavior and changing pages_per_range to a smaller value (like 12 or even 1) should make things much better overall.

Too bad it doesn't support my UNIQUE requirement. Any ideas? A RULE of some sort?

Comment: Ah good point about the include in PG11. I forgot about the UNIQUE constraint when I wrote the P.S., so that idea wouldn't have worked anyway.